Path to pip broken - pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
if i do this from terminal in PyCharm  just try to install the package with pip.
(venv) PS C:\Development\Citizenship\video_auto_generator> pip install python-dotenv                            

I get

pip : The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that
the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1

pip install python-dotenv

+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (pip:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException




However if i do
(venv) PS C:\Development\Citizenship\video_auto_generator> venv\Scripts\python.exe -m pip install python-dotenv

and supply the path to python in the venv directory. it works.

Collecting python-dotenv
Using cached python_dotenv-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl.metadata (23 kB)
Using cached python_dotenv-1.0.1-py3-none-any.whl (19 kB)
Installing collected packages: python-dotenv
Successfully installed python-dotenv-1.0.1

This works in another project i have but its broken in my new project.
Python 3.12.  Im having so many issues with this since upgrading to 3.12 i cant get a new project crated that works out of the box with venv it takes forever to debug issues.
This also works
py -m pip install python-dotenv

Why cant i just type pip install like i used to.
update
"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate

which give me invalid interpreter in pycharm and then i try to feed it the path to python and i get

Error: Python packaging tool 'setuptools' not found

if i try to then create a new venv via pycharm i get pip :

The term 'pip' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet

i suspect this is something silly but i cant get anything to work now and its a big problem.
even
py -m pip list 

on some of my projects fails that it cant find pip

update 2
If i create a new project it works fine
"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate
echo python-dotenv > requirements.txt
type nul > .env
type nul > app.py
type nul > README.MD
pip install -r requirements.txt
pip list

However if i do this in an existing project.
"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate

and try to use that in PyCharm I get.  how can it be invalid.


How did you create the virtual environment? This should just work but if you used nonstandard options or an nonstandard tool like uv to create the venv the expectations will be different.

"C:\Program Files\Python312\python.exe" -m venv venv  <-- from current directory

wondering if it could have something to do with main.cpython-39.pyc its in pycache

it seems that distutils  was deprecated in python version 3.10 so the venv creation doesn't include it.  which calls the project to fail.
this fixes it.
pip install setuptools

